# Isometry action $SO(3)\times SO(3)\to SO(3)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

There exists an isometry action of $SO(3)$ over $SO(3)$?

I have been trying to prove that the natural action $SO(3)\times GL(3,\mathbb R)\to GL(3,\mathbb R)$, $(A,B)\mapsto A\cdot B$ is an isometry action respect to the metric $g=dx_{\alpha}^\beta\otimes dx_\beta^\alpha$. Unfortunately it is not an isometry action.

Any help?

Comment: The question is senseless as long as you don't specify a metric. For the same reason as you can act on a metric space by group automorphisms if you don't specify a group structure.

Comment: I guess it would help to stop trying to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ can act on itself by isometries, then the answer is yes. Put any left/right invariant Riemannian metric on $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ and then the action of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ on itself by left/right translations is by definition an action by isometries.